# jQuery - Create a grid over image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a "grid" over an image, where each square/grid is clickable (is a link).

Currently, what I have is this:

```
<div style="background:url('/images/gridimg/progrid08.jpg') no-repeat #E9E9E9;width:601px;height:400px;margin:0 auto;border-left:1px solid #3d5a7f;border-top:1px solid #3d5a7f;" id="drawTable"></div>

function drawTable(){
var x = 30;
var y = 20;
var t = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="grxd">';
    for(var i=1;i<=(x*y);i++){
        t += (i==1 ? '<tr>' : '');
        t += '<td style="cursor:pointer;"></td>';
        if(i==(x*y)){
            t += '</tr>';
        } else {
            t += (i%30===0 ? '</tr><tr>' : '');
        }

    }
    t += '</table>';
$("#drawTable").html(t);
}
```

Although the above script doesn't make any grid. It's supposed to make it a grid.

Can anyone help me in the right direction?

This is what I am trying to achieve: [image]

Comment: can you write example link what you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Javascript code looks okay to me. I think the issue is perhaps related to your styling of the table. I put together a Fiddle for you - see last link.

```
<div id="drawTable" style="background:url('https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQiX43nTAcsgpYUlK0MarurfXV_Hx2w53BonmYbKJUNyO4GJ35Q');width:275px; height:183px"></div>
```

Your function (unchaged):

```
function drawTable() {
var x = 30;
var y = 20;
var t = '<table cellspacing="0" border="1" cellpadding="0" class="grxd">';
for (var i = 1; i <= (x * y); i++) {
    t += (i == 1 ? '<tr>' : '');
    t += '<td style="cursor:pointer;"></td>';
    if (i == (x * y)) {
        t += '</tr>';
    } else {
        t += (i % 30 === 0 ? '</tr><tr>' : '');
    }

}
t += '</table>';
$("#drawTable").html(t);
```

}

And this is the CSS I added:

```
table>td {
    border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
table.grxd {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/93cyX/1/

Answer (score 0):

Get the width and height of the image, and based on this create a table. After this make image as a background of the table.

Answer (score 0):

This is definately not the best approach and even quick and dirty, but I hope it gives you an idea how to solve your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/fJRFK/15/

The general idea is to fill the div with number n of block-styled links and identify them by their id's.

```
<div class="image-holder" id="img-1" style="background:url('http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/stardust.png');">

</div>

$gridsize = 10;

$(".image-holder").each(function() {
    $linkheight = ($(this).innerHeight() / $gridsize) - 1;
    $linkwidth = ($(this).innerWidth() / $gridsize) - 1;

    for($i = 0; $i < $gridsize * $gridsize; $i++) {
        $currentId = $(this).attr('id') + '-' + $i;

        $(this).append('<a href="test.html" class="grid-link" style="height:' +         $linkheight + 'px;width:' + $linkwidth + 'px;" id="' + $currentId + '"></a>');
    }
});
```